# arrange the functions in increasing order of growth rate

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, discrete-optimization

I am supposed to arrange the functions into increasing order of growth rates.

$$3^n, 2^n, n2^n, n^{30}, (\log n)^3, \sqrt{n}\log^2 n, n\log n, \sqrt{n!}, n^{29}+n^{27}, n^{2\sqrt{n}}$$

I came up with the following

$$(\log n)^3 < \sqrt{n}\log^2 n < n\log n < n^{29}+n^{27} < n^{30} < 2^n < n2^n < 3^n < n^{2\sqrt{n}} < \sqrt{n!}$$

However, I am not confident in my answer and was looking for feedback. Did I do it right?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE! Please format your question using MathJax. [This page](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) should give you a start at learning how to typeset mathematics here so that your posts say what you want them to, and also look good.

Comment: You are good up to the exponentials. When comparing them, try taking the logarithms of both. Since the logarithm is increasing, this won't change which is bigger.